# Maximizing a piecewise-linear convex function

Tags: discrete-geometry, oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

<sub>[Crossposted](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/5894) on Operations Research SE.</sub>

---

I am working on an optimization problem where some of the terms of the objective function to maximize are expressed as a piecewise linear function of variables:

$$ z =  \begin{cases} 
      c^- x, & x \leq 0 \\
      c^+ x, & x    > 0 \\
   \end{cases} $$

as depicted below

[image: objective function plot]

When I have $c^- \geq c^+$, I can solve the problem by adding a new variable $x'$, and two constraints:

- $x' \leq c^- \times x $
- $x' \leq c^+ \times x $

But what do I do when $c^- < c^+$ ? I don't think there is a way to express the problem as a linear  programming problem in that case, is there ?

I have heard about [SOS constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set). Are they the canonical way to solve this kind of problem ? If my problem contains many such piecewise linear functions, is it reasonable to expect a free solver from being able to solve such a problem with thousands of SOS1 constraints ?

#### Example

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{maximize} & a \max(x,0) + b \min(x,0) + c \max(y,0) + d \min(y,0)\\ \text{subject to} & x,y \in [−1,1]\end{array}$$

Comment: I would write $c_+$ instead, since $c^+$ is a bit too close to $c$ transposed.

Comment: When $c^- > c^+$, you can solve the problem because it is *convex*. When $c^- < c^+$, the problem is non-convex.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the feasible region is not convex. So the question is: what is the canonical way of solving such problems ?

Comment: Yes, the objective function is piecewise linear and all the variables are bounded, so the objective has a finite maximum.

Comment: Every $\min$ / $\max$ introduces a Boolean variable. Thus, in your example, you have $2^4 = 16$ "branches". The maximum of each of these branches can be found via LP. Lastly, find the $\max$ of the $16$ maxima. There are smarter ways of doing it. If you can determine whether the objective to be maximized is concave, it is much easier.

Comment: The number of branches grows exponentially with the number of variables, and I don't think it's possible to solve billions of linear programs in a reasonable amount of time. What are the smarter ways of doing it ? I can determine whether the objective is concave: it is not :p

Comment: Exactly. The number of branches does grow exponentially with the number of variables, but it should grow according to $2^n$, whereas in your example, if one is sloppy, it grows according to $2^{2n}$. Isn't the existence of problems whose average-case instances are infeasible that makes cryptography possible? In my humble opinion, you should move this question to https://or.stackexchange.com which is where the experts on combinatorial optimization are.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that. Is there a way to move a question from one site to another, or should I delete it here and create a new one there ?

Comment: I suppose you can flag your own question and request that it be moved. Or, you can re-post there and cross-link them, so that if it is answered in one site, people on the other site will know.

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/maximizing-a-piecewise-linear-convex-function